# Package.js Multiple versions of fbjs found

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, yarnpkg

I have the following error message when I try update 0.10.5 to 0.11.0. I do not even have gbjs in my package.js file.

```
[compileVendorDll] ERROR in fbjs
[compileVendorDll]   Multiple versions of fbjs found:
[compileVendorDll]     0.8.17 ./~/fbjs from ./~/fbjs/lib/warning.js
[compileVendorDll]     1.0.0 ./~/draft-js/~/fbjs from ./~/draft-js/lib/DraftEditorDragHandler.js
```

Does anyone know how I could go about resolving this?

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Comment: can you `npm list fbjs` , if `fbjs` isn't the correct name of the package that caused that error please correct it before doing that command in your terminal, and provide a screenshot for the result

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have, in your project the version `0.8.17` of the package `fbjs` and you also happen to have `draft-js` which has the same package `fbjs` version `1.0.0` as a dependency, but, the problem caused because the version in `draft-js` package doesn't fit with the one you have.

Consider this: upgrading `fbjs` to the same version as `draft-js` which is `1.0.0` to possibly fix the problem..

In your command line *terminal* type one of the following:

```
npm install fbjs@1.0.0 --save-dev
// Or
yarn add fbjs@1.0.0 --dev
```

Note that `fbjs` package's latest version is `1.0.0`